# Server to server API messaging

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I've a Sails.js app that is distributed across multiple regions for redundancy. I'm finding the need though for these APIs to be able to fire out messages and the other APIs react. For instance, if one API updates the config held in the DB, I need the others to reload that new config from the DB.

I know that I obviously need some sort of messaging bus, but I'm wondering if there is a Sails specific preferred way of doing this. I'm aware that Sails has an "Admin bus" but I'm yet to use it, and can find no documentation on it, which implies to me that it's used for internal purposes.

With the Sails Redis socket functionality, is that used simply for server->client communication or can it be used for server->server also?

Is the answer I'm looking for to simply implement a 3rd party messaging bus?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a sails specific way of doing it using it's sockets. I've gone for an easy option, and am using [busmq](https://github.com/capriza/node-busmq)'s pubsub which seems a nice way of doing things. Supports ioredis also.